# OSB12C:how to eliminate the wadl in REST

Tags: oracle, osb

i am creating a rest reference from an existing wadl in OSB12C then it is creating a wadl and wsdl of itsef.As i am refering to the existing wadl i dont want the REST to make the extra wadl.can anyone helpout??

Answer (score 0):

You can remove any existing wadl/wsdl that are generated automatically,  just remove any existing reference to the new document (use the show usage option).